# I am trying to write a program with Gomoku which can judge whether who is the winner

Tags: c

I am trying to write a C program but failed.I just got 60% of the scores from the judgement program.I want to find and learn why my program can't work.Can you help me?
This is the example input and output.This game starts with a 15x15 board.
input:H 8 I 9 H 9 H 10 I 10 J 8 I 7 K 7 H 7 G 11 output:The winner is white.
If white wins, print out "The winner is white.”, otherwise, print out "The winner is black."
If no one wins, print out "The game is tie"
If there is an invalid move, print out "Invalid move at step __."

I have tried hard to solve it but I only get 60% of scores from the judgement program.I really need your help.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int check_winh (int[15][15]);
int check_winv (int[15][15]);
int check_wind1 (int[15][15]);
int check_wind2 (int[15][15]);
int main() {
    int v[15][15] = {0},i,j,c=0, a, b, d=0,n=0, p=0,w=0,k=0,winner=0;
    while (scanf(" %c %d", &a, &b) != EOF && b>=0 && b<=14 && a>=65 && a<=79) {
        a = a-65;
        c++;
        if (c % 2 != 0 ) {
            if (v[a][b] == 0) {
                v[a][b] = 1;
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }else{
            if(v[a][b] == 0) {
                v[a][b] = 2;
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
        d++;
    }
    if (c != d) {
        printf("Invalid move at step %d\n", c);
    }else {
        winner = check_winh(v);
    if (winner == 0) {
        winner = check_winv(v);
    }
    if (winner == 0) {
        winner = check_wind1(v);
    }
    if (winner == 0) {
        winner = check_wind2(v);
    }
        if (winner == 1) {
            printf("The winner is black.\n");
        }else if(winner == 2) {
            printf("The winner is white.\n");
        }else {
            printf("The game is tie.\n");
        }
       }
    return 0;
}
int check_winh (int v[15][15]) {
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<=14; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<=10; j++) {
            if (v[i][j] == 1 && v[i][j+1] == 1 && v[i][j+2] == 1 && v[i][j+3] == 1 &&v[i][j+4] == 1) {
                return 1;
            }else if (v[i][j] == 2 && v[i][j+1] == 2 && v[i][j+2] == 2 && v[i][j+3] == 2 &&v[i][j+4] == 2){
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int check_winv (int v[15][15]) {
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<=14; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<=14; j++) {
            if (v[j][i] == 1 && v[j+1][i] == 1 && v[j+2][i] == 1 && v[j+3][i] == 1 && v[j+4][i] == 1) {
                return 1;
            }else if (v[j][i] == 2 && v[j+1][i] == 2 && v[j+2][i] == 2 && v[j+3][i] == 2 && v[j+4][i] == 2){
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int check_wind1 (int v[15][15]) {
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<=10; i++){
        for (j=0; j<=10-i; j++) {
            if (v[i+j][j] == 1 && v[i+j+1][j+1] == 1 && v[i+j+2][j+2] == 1 && v[i+j+3][j+3] == 1 && v[i+j+4][j+4] == 1) {
                return 1;
            }else if (v[i+j][j] == 2 && v[i+j+1][j+1] == 2 && v[i+j+2][j+2] == 2 && v[i+j+3][j+3] == 2 && v[i+j+4][j+4] == 2) {
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int check_wind2 (int v[15][15]) {
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<=10; i++){
        for (j=0; j<=10-i; j++) {
            if (v[j][i+j] == 1 && v[j+1][i+j+1] == 1 && v[j+2][i+j+2] == 1 && v[j+3][i+j+3] == 1 && v[j+4][i+j+4] == 1) {
                return 1;
            }else if (v[j][i+j] == 2 && v[j+1][i+j+1] == 2 && v[j+2][i+j+2] == 2 && v[j+3][i+j+3] == 2 && v[j+4][i+j+4] == 2) {
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: Don't do `a>=65 && a<=79`, use [`isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) instead. And if the user gives the wrong input for the number, your checks will fail. Also note that `a - 65` is not portable or standard. Please try to avoid using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). And please give your variables some better and meaningful names (like for example `c`, what is is supposed to be used for? How well does the name `c` describe that use?)